# Blocked by play protect [Ionic Project]

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, google-play-services, google-play-protect

I have an Ionic project (it's quite an old project) and when i install it a message blocked by Play Protect appears (as in screenshot). what is the solution? what can I do from the code side of my project?[image]

Comment: Have you published your app on the Play Store?

Comment: Actually, this is not my App or my project, i just asked my supervisor to help fix this case, i have checked it on Play Store and this app is not there sir..

Comment: Once the app has been uploaded on the Play Store, this message won't be shown. Whenever you try to install an app outside from the Play Store, Google shows warning for untrusted developers.

Comment: But some of my applications have not been uploaded to the Playstore and when the APK will be installed on the smartphone, the Google Play Protect message does not appear. what makes this difference sir?

Comment: It depends on multiple factors. You can read here https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2812853?hl=en